# Why does the function chunkBy parse strings into integer?

Tags: d

In the snippet below I want to split a string into repeated characters. The cunkBy function seems to return the parsed int value instead of strings. Why does this happen?

```
import std.stdio, std.algorithm, std.array, std.conv: to;

void main() {
    //writeln("12236666".chunkBy!((a, b) => a == b).any!(a => a.to!string().length == 2));
    writeln("12236666".chunkBy!((a, b) => a == b)); // prints [1, 22, 3, 6666] 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it is just printing strings without quotes. There's no parsing going on there at all.

Comment: Is this an inconsistent behavior? writeln(["354", "1"]); would print ["354", "1"]

Comment: Also this seems to fail: `writeln("12236666".chunkBy!((a, b) => a == b).any!(a => a.length == 2));` but something like this works fine: `writeln(["354", "1"].any!(a => a.length == 2));`

Comment: `writeln("12236666".chunkBy!((a, b) => a == b).map!"typeid(a.array)")`. output: `[dchar[], dchar[], dchar[], dchar[]]`. This also works: `"12236666".chunkBy!((a, b) => a == b).any!(a => a.array.length == 2)`. The errors you get show that you're dealing with range types like `ChunkbyImpl` and `ChunkByImpl.Group`. writeln() doesn't know about those so its fallback printer differs from how it prints stuff like a direct `string[]`